# Juju unable to remove relation

Tags: juju, maas

I am trying to remove and re add the relation between openstack-dashboard and the identity service.

I have 2 units of the dashboard service and I have made an HA cluster out of it, and also I have 2 units of the identity service with the HA cluster subordinate charm.

All 4 units are in the "started" sate, not in error state.

I try running running the following command:

```
xsmaas01:~$ sudo juju remove-relation openstack-dashboard keystone --debug
[sudo] password for sonali: 
2013-11-05 12:31:11 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environprovider.go:32 opening environment "maas".
2013-11-05 12:31:11 DEBUG juju state.go:160 waiting for DNS name(s) of state server instances [/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-bc3afec8-19f2-11e3-8cf9-c6d6cdbfe570/]
2013-11-05 12:31:11 INFO juju.state open.go:68 opening state; mongo addresses: ["jujuzk.master:37017"]; entity ""
2013-11-05 12:31:11 INFO juju.state open.go:106 connection established
2013-11-05 12:31:11 INFO juju supercommand.go:286 command finished
```

and in juju debug-log I see this:

```
jujuzk:2013-11-05 12:30:41 DEBUG juju codec.go:103 rpc/jsoncodec: <- {"RequestId":37,"Type":"Pinger","Request":"Ping","Params":{}}
jujuzk:2013-11-05 12:30:41 DEBUG juju codec.go:168 rpc/jsoncodec: -> {"RequestId":37,"Response":{}}
jujuzk:2013-11-05 12:30:41 DEBUG juju codec.go:103 rpc/jsoncodec: <- {"RequestId":37,"Type":"Pinger","Request":"Ping","Params":{}}
jujuzk:2013-11-05 12:30:41 DEBUG juju codec.go:168 rpc/jsoncodec: -> {"RequestId":37,"Response":{}}
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 DEBUG juju filter.go:311 worker/uniter/filter: got relations change
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 DEBUG juju filter.go:339 worker/uniter/filter: sent relations event
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju uniter.go:350 worker/uniter: running "identity-service-relation-departed" hook
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju context.go:174 worker/uniter: skipped "identity-service-relation-departed" hook (not implemented)
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju uniter.go:358 worker/uniter: ran "identity-service-relation-departed" hook
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju uniter.go:365 worker/uniter: committing "relation-departed" hook
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju uniter.go:383 worker/uniter: committed "relation-departed" hook
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju uniter.go:350 worker/uniter: running "identity-service-relation-departed" hook
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju context.go:174 worker/uniter: skipped "identity-service-relation-departed" hook (not implemented)
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju uniter.go:358 worker/uniter: ran "identity-service-relation-departed" hook
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju uniter.go:365 worker/uniter: committing "relation-departed" hook
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju uniter.go:383 worker/uniter: committed "relation-departed" hook
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju uniter.go:350 worker/uniter: running "identity-service-relation-broken" hook
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju context.go:174 worker/uniter: skipped "identity-service-relation-broken" hook (not implemented)
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju uniter.go:358 worker/uniter: ran "identity-service-relation-broken" hook
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju uniter.go:365 worker/uniter: committing "relation-broken" hook
opdashboard01:2013-11-05 12:31:23 INFO juju uniter.go:383 worker/uniter: committed "relation-broken" hook
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju uniter.go:350 worker/uniter: running "identity-service-relation-departed" hook
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju context.go:174 worker/uniter: skipped "identity-service-relation-departed" hook (not implemented)
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju uniter.go:358 worker/uniter: ran "identity-service-relation-departed" hook
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju uniter.go:365 worker/uniter: committing "relation-departed" hook
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 DEBUG juju filter.go:311 worker/uniter/filter: got relations change
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju uniter.go:383 worker/uniter: committed "relation-departed" hook
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 DEBUG juju filter.go:339 worker/uniter/filter: sent relations event
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju uniter.go:350 worker/uniter: running "identity-service-relation-departed" hook
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju context.go:174 worker/uniter: skipped "identity-service-relation-departed" hook (not implemented)
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju uniter.go:358 worker/uniter: ran "identity-service-relation-departed" hook
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju uniter.go:365 worker/uniter: committing "relation-departed" hook
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju uniter.go:383 worker/uniter: committed "relation-departed" hook
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju uniter.go:350 worker/uniter: running "identity-service-relation-broken" hook
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju context.go:174 worker/uniter: skipped "identity-service-relation-broken" hook (not implemented)
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju uniter.go:358 worker/uniter: ran "identity-service-relation-broken" hook
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju uniter.go:365 worker/uniter: committing "relation-broken" hook
opks03:2013-11-05 12:31:33 INFO juju uniter.go:383 worker/uniter: committed "relation-broken" hook
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 DEBUG juju filter.go:311 worker/uniter/filter: got relations change
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 DEBUG juju filter.go:339 worker/uniter/filter: sent relations event
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju uniter.go:350 worker/uniter: running "identity-service-relation-departed" hook
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju context.go:174 worker/uniter: skipped "identity-service-relation-departed" hook (not implemented)
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju uniter.go:358 worker/uniter: ran "identity-service-relation-departed" hook
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju uniter.go:365 worker/uniter: committing "relation-departed" hook
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju uniter.go:383 worker/uniter: committed "relation-departed" hook
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju uniter.go:383 worker/uniter: committed "relation-departed" hook
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju uniter.go:350 worker/uniter: running "identity-service-relation-broken" hook
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju context.go:174 worker/uniter: skipped "identity-service-relation-broken" hook (not implemented)
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju uniter.go:358 worker/uniter: ran "identity-service-relation-broken" hook
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju uniter.go:365 worker/uniter: committing "relation-broken" hook
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju uniter.go:383 worker/uniter: committed "relation-broken" hook
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju uniter.go:350 worker/uniter: running "identity-service-relation-departed" hook
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju context.go:174 worker/uniter: skipped "identity-service-relation-departed" hook (not implemented)
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju uniter.go:358 worker/uniter: ran "identity-service-relation-departed" hook
opdashboard02:2013-11-05 12:31:26 INFO juju uniter.go:365 worker/uniter: committing "relation-departed" hook
opks01:2013-11-05 12:32:19 DEBUG juju filter.go:311 worker/uniter/filter: got relations change
jujuzk:2013-11-05 12:31:32 DEBUG juju codec.go:103 rpc/jsoncodec: <- {"RequestId":38,"Type":"Pinger","Request":"Ping","Params":{}}
jujuzk:2013-11-05 12:31:32 DEBUG juju codec.go:168 rpc/jsoncodec: -> {"RequestId":38,"Response":{}}
jujuzk:2013-11-05 12:31:38 DEBUG juju codec.go:103 rpc/jsoncodec: <- {"RequestId":13,"Type":"Pinger","Request":"Ping","Params":{}}
jujuzk:2013-11-05 12:31:38 DEBUG juju codec.go:168 rpc/jsoncodec: -> {"RequestId":13,"Response":{}}

jujuzk:2013-11-05 12:32:31 DEBUG juju codec.go:103 rpc/jsoncodec: <- {"Type":"Client","Request":"SetAnnotations","Params":{"Tag":"service-openstack-dashboard","Pairs":{"gui-x":"1917.0029802730883","gui-y":"-470.82699030543813"}},"RequestId":41}
jujuzk:2013-11-05 12:32:31 DEBUG juju codec.go:168 rpc/jsoncodec: -> {"RequestId":41,"Response":{}}
jujuzk:2013-11-05 12:32:32 DEBUG juju codec.go:103 rpc/jsoncodec: <- {"RequestId":39,"Type":"Pinger","Request":"Ping","Params":{}}
jujuzk:2013-11-05 12:32:32 DEBUG juju codec.go:168 rpc/jsoncodec: -> {"RequestId":39,"Response":{}}
jujuzk:2013-11-05 12:32:35 DEBUG juju codec.go:168 rpc/jsoncodec: -> {"RequestId":5,"Response":{"Deltas":[["annotation","change",{"Tag":"service-openstack-dashboard","Annotations":{"gui-x":"1917.0029802730883","gui-y":"-470.82699030543813"}}]]}}
jujuzk:2013-11-05 12:32:35 DEBUG juju codec.go:103 rpc/jsoncodec: <- {"Type":"AllWatcher","Request":"Next","Id":"1","Params":{},"RequestId":42}
```

But still I can see relation still exists. Also, if re-add relation it says relation already exists, so it can not add the relation.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your juju status after running remove relation? Odds are there is a unit in an error state. If a unit errors during removal it won't remove the relation. You'll need to run `juju resolved` against that errored unit to have the relation removal continue.

Answer (score -1):

I am not too familiar with Juju, but this may help or give you an idea of what to do.

https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/authors-implicit-relations.html

https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/charms-relations.html

What about "juju destroy-relation"?

Comment: `juju destroy-relation`